# Initial setup after deploy Spring app

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, installation

I have a Spring MVC app that needs some data after deploy. I need the first user to give me this data through some forms in a similar way to Wordpress, Drupal or any of that apps with a setup process on the first lunch. I also have a pair of Autowired classes that  need some variables provided by the user so I need to delay them until the variables are persisted in the embedded database. Is there a way to do this?

I've been searching how can this be accomplish but I've only found an answer to a question in this site and I don't get how this work nor if it is a good solution. This is the question: [How to write a Spring/JavaEE/web application installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364836/how-to-write-a-spring-javaee-web-application-installer)

Comment: Have you heard of Spring MVC?

Comment: I'm using Spring MVC. What do you mean with that?

Comment: Oh ok, it wasn't clear by your description. You understand that your question is quite vague, right? I would suggest googling for "Spring MVC form example".

Comment: Ok, I'm going to improve it a little. Thank you ;)

Comment: Can you show us one of this `Autowired classes that need some variables provided by the user so `.

Answer (score 0):

Usually spring beans are stateless. They can read *variables* from database when this is needed. I think your design is wrong.